# How can i remove my alpha version with high version code from Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have apk on Alpha testing stage.

I'm new, and when i learned to use Google Play Console, i published my app into alpha testing, rising version code(i thought it's ok and i can remove all versions easly).

Now i have apk with versionCode = 12.

[image]

When i want to download new alpha version, i need to raise my versionCode(or Googele Play will not pass it). And, if i understand it clear, when i want to publish my final version, it will be with raised versionCode too. But i want to releaze my apk with version code = 1.

So i must to remove old versions somehow. How can i do this?

Maybe i wrong and there is a better way to do smth, what can i do in my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google doesn't allow the same package name to be released with a lower version code, because it would managing versions harder. Just imagine someone having version code 12 and then suddenly going to version code 1 then 5 then 3. It makes it complicated and google doesn't know if you are trying to upload an old version or a new version.

So sadly the only way to release an app with version code 1 is to change the package name and create a new release. Your version code shouldn't matter though. Your users generally don't see it. So I'd recommend just going to the next version code. What the users do see is the version name. The version name doesn't have these restrictions so you can set your version name to something like `version 1` for example

Comment: Oh, sadly to hear it. But it's logical.

I don't want to change package name just because of it, so i continue to releaze my apk with current versionCode. Ty.